# How to check my git commit code quality using pylint?

Tags: python, git, pylint, pep8

I want to figure want the score for my code is using pylint. I can do this for all the files that were changed in the commit using the following script

```
#!/bin/sh
# Auto-check for pep8 so I don't check in bad code
FILES=$(git show --name-only | grep -e '\.py$')

if [ -n "$FILES"  ]; then
    pylint $FILES
fi
```

But what I really want is to run pylint(or any other static analysis tool for python) only on the lines I have added to the file, and get the pylint score for them.

Comment: I don’t think it’s possible to run linters only on single lines. And I wonder if it would even work, considering that changes in one line could affect all the lines around it.

Comment: You could run pylint over the files before your changes are applied, then over the changed files and report if the number of pylint warnings has increased.

Comment: @snakecharmerb: This is what I am doing right now. But with this I get a lot of errors, even for the code which is not a part of my commit. Is there any way I could let's say filter out the errors I am getting (say using a line number range or maybe using function names?)

Comment: I think the usual approach would to fix the problems first. Not sure if you are following the best approach there, trying to work around an error output that shouldn’t exist in the first place (you should aim for not having errors in the code to begin with, making the thing you are working on here only a temporary solution for a temporary problem).